# Multiple time series sequence prediction for multiple multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, lstm, sequence-to-sequence, sequential-pattern-mining

My question is somehow similar to [this question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/45882/lstm-time-series-prediction-for-multiple-multivariate-series), but not satisfied with the answer. I have `100 samples`, each sample consists of `6 time-series`, (let's say `[X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, Y]`) of length `200`. Each sample is independent of each other. I want to build a time-series model, which will take one sample `(300, 5)` as input and predict Y `(300, 1)` as output.

LSTM relates the various windows (in my case sample) while making the model, which is undesirable in my case. Though I tried I tried it and but could not achieve good results. This is the actual and predicted value of some of the samples. We observe that, prediction is happening in a narrow band between 35000 to 50000 for most of the cases. My intuition is LSTM has learnt only the latest sample passed and making prediction based on that. [image]
Further more, I thought of using ARIMAX, but same problem will arise there as well. I tried CNN as well which was predicting better than LSTM but not close to actual values.

So my question is: what will be best strategy to train such model where it takes a 2D time series data as input, learn the temporal dependency of the X and Y and predict time series sequence of Y.